# c++ iterators to list in a generic functions

Tags: c++, stl

Here is the code , where i am trying to simulate Queue using STL lists , the class is

```
template <class T>
class myqueue{
    list<T> m;
public:
    void enqueue(T item);
    T dequeue();
    void display();
};
```

Here is the implementation of display function where I want to display the contents of the list `m`, with the use of iterators .

```
template <class T>
void myqueue<T>::display(){
    // list<T>::iterator it;
    for (auto it = m.begin(); it < m.end(); it++)
    std::cout << *it;
}
```

and I am continuously getting the error Need help on this, This has been resolved I should have used `!=` instead of `<` in the For Loop

**EDIT :**

```
template <class T>
void myqueue<T>::display() {
   // list<T>::iterator it;
    for (list<T>::iterator it = m.begin(); it < m.end(); it++)
    std::cout << *it;
}
```

and I am getting the error as

```
"31:13: error: need 'typename' before 'std::list<T>::iterator' because 'std::list<T>' is a dependent scope"
```

if I use keyword `auto` it works fine. What is the reason behind it ??

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: It should be it != m.end()

Comment: You may want to consider a `deque` instead of a `list` for your queue.

Comment: can you point us error ?

Comment: Now that my error is resolved , it should have been !=   i have edited the original post to ask one more thing

Comment: But in general for the next time: add the error message to the question when you get errors. Also don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(auto it = m.begin();it<m.end();it++)
```

should be

```
for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++)
```

or simply:

```
for (const auto& e : m)
```

Comment: the error was ": error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'std::_List_iterator<int>' and 'std::list<int, std::allocator<int> >::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator<int>}')
31:31: note: candidates are:  " and now i understand the problem , thanks for your help

Comment: @KapilBhandari: Insert error message not in comment, but directly in your question. And when you answer in comment, do it in the thread where the question was asked: there is one thread comment for the question, and one for each answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion , updated in the question

Comment: And for your `typename` error, message seems clear enough: you should write `typename std::list<T>::iterator`.

Comment: You could also not use any loop at all but rather `std::copy` as in `std::copy(m.begin(), m.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout));`.